# which tool to compare these two different applications

Tags: tooltip

I want to compare two different file uploading /downloading application.

Basically the scenarios would be, I want to measure the time taken by each application for uploading a file/downloading a file.

One way of doing that is using a stop watch and monitoring the upload and download. 
I am looking for a tool which would record the time taken when the upload /download completes.

Comment: This would be more appropriate for superuser.stackexchange.com

Comment: @poolie It looks like a software recommendation question, so it might be more appropriate for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.